# Left Ideal right ideal identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If the left ideal equals the right ideal (denoted as $I$) in a ring $R$ does that mean $rI = Ir = I$ for any $r$ inside $R$?

Also, in general, if left ideal is the same as right ideal in a ring, does that mean the ring is commutative? (I think that if the ring is commutative, then any right ideal is the same as left ideal)

Comment: What do you mean “**the** left ideal equals **the** right ideal”?

Comment: $rI=I$ holds only if $r$ is a unit.This is an example $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal in itself. However $n\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}$ for any $n\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: @youssefmousaaid that is false: $r$ need not be a unit.  For example if e is an idempotent in a commutative ring, $e(eR)$= eR$ , and we can find nonunit idempotents.

Comment: @rschwieb Okey!Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

A ring is called **right duo** If all of its right ideals are also left ideals.

[There exist one-sided duo rings](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84l&L=84r)

A right-and-left duo ring does not have to be commutative. Example: the quaternions.

> if $I$ is a left and right ideal does $Ir=I=rI$ for all r ?

No, it only means $rI\subseteq I$ and $Ir\subseteq I$.  As mentioned in the comments, any nonzero ideal of $\mathbb Z$ will  be an example for you.

Comment: I mean "if I is both a left ideal and a right ideal, does that mean Ir = rI = I for any r inside R?" Sorry for the confusion